# Package dependencies. Class is implemented in both... One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. How to fix?

Tags: swift, frameworks

I intentionally replaced all pods with package dependencies. But the problem "class is implemented in both..." remained. When I run my workspace on the simulator I get a lot of warnings. In "Build phases" all dependencies are set as "optional". I know these warnings aren't critical, but this spam is very annoying. How to fix it?

```
objc[40017]: Class _EXRunningExtension is implemented in both
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Develope
    r/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/
    Library/Frameworks/ExtensionFoundation.framework/ExtensionFoundation (0x7ff864a43f90) a
    nd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Devel
    oper/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Syst
    em/Library/Frameworks/ExtensionFoundation.framework/ExtensionFoundation (0x1508abd48). 
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Moreover, all these warnings are related to ExtensionFoundation framework. But I can't find any description of this framework. What is it responsible for?